# Devise not signing up users

Tags: devise, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

When signup is clicked it just keeps loading. No runtime error on the server no error is shown anywhere.

I followed the sequence on the gem installation, generated views, generated model User. rake db:migrate.

I expected to signup users but just keeps loading on the browser with no error.

Comment: Can you share your log information when you click on sign-up?

Comment: That's the thing nothing happens on the server , the browser just keeps loading and nothing happens after sign up is clicked.

Comment: Maybe pair programming with you will help using Zoom, so that you can share your screen, which will help us debug the issue gradually.